# Show some options about username

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

When we try to put a username when subscribing to a site, it will decline our choice and show us some usernames which can be chosen by us. For example if I put Junaid, the site shows me the options Junaid1123, Junaid444... How can I do that for my site?

Comment: Just force the username to be email address; those are unique and the user will appreciate not having to remember another username.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Use javascript to get the entered username from the form.
2) Send a synchronous ajax request containing the entered username to a program on your server.
3) Have your server program check if the entered username is in your database.
3) If the entered username is not in your database, then create an array of 5 random numbers.
4) Create an array of 5 strings, where each string consists of the username added to each of the random numbers.
5) Check your db for the 5 usernames, and eliminate any that already exist.  Create more as necessary. 
6) Send back five usernames in the response.
7) Use js to display the five names to the user.
```